What are System fonts and where are they used?
With the system colors I can kind of envision why they are there



type
used by




Primary
Default background color of a page


Secondary
a slightly different shade for header/footer/aside


Text
Default color of text


Accent
The same as secondary but a different shade (?)



But what is this with the system fonts?



type
used where




Primary
default text? but than what is Text?


Secondary
Headings?


Text
if not Primary?


Accent
this could be <em> or <strong>?



if I search for fonts I find sites explaining what fonts are, where to get them but if and where they are used.
(Btw. I'm a seasoned web developer so colors and fonts are not new but primary , secondary, text, accent have no direct meaning to me)

"System fonts", as I understand it, is the use of fonts already present on a user's computer, ie, not using Google Fonts or some other solution. It saves time, since the page will be displayed in a font already on the user's machine. There are a number of system font stacks -- here's one set of examples.

This might be a more useful link than the Github one I provided in my earlier comment: https://modernfontstacks.com/
